# Rails / Creating a Blog: Validation for comments (belong to a post) does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a simple blog, where a post has many comments and the comments are displayed on the posts#show page.

I have two bugs which I cannot figure out:

1. Validations for my comments are not working. The name and the content of a comment should be present. Whenever I try to submit an "empty" comment I got an error message: "NoMethodError in CommentsController#create: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass". I suspect that in my comments_controller.rb I have to render a different page in my create action (see below for code)?
2. Whenever I create a new post, there is always an empty "delete" link belonging to an empty comment (which no one has created. It was created automatically?). This "delete" link links to http://localhost:3000/posts/[post_id]/comments (note that after "/comments" there is no comment_id like "/comment/3/" e.g.)

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**app/models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  belongs_to :post
end
```

**app/controllers/comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment saved!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong!"
      render root_path                        # I suspect here is an error?
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    flash[:success] = "Comment deleted"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

    def comment_params 
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :content)
    end

    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end
end
```

**app/views/posts/show.html.erb**

Here is the problem that a "Delete" link shows up whenever I create a new post. This "Delete" link belongs to a comment which is empty and strangely created automatically?

```
<% unless @post.comments.empty? %>          # I suspect here is an error?
  <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.name %></p>
    <p><%= comment.content %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Delete",   [comment.post, comment], 
                                method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/posts/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= @post.errors.count %> Fehler:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="image-box">
    <p><%= f.file_field :image%></p>
  </div>
    <div class="title-box">
      <p><%= f.label :title, "Titel" %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :title, class: "title-field"%></p>
    </div>
     <div class="content-box">
      <p><%= f.label :content, "Inhalt" %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_area :content, class: "content-field"%></p>
    </div>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For your first problem, it would be interesting to investigate why `@post.comments` is nil. I'd be for debugging with `binding.pry` here to see what's the value of a @post.

For your second problem, I would also try to see what are the value of `comment`

Comment: For the 2nd problem: When I create a new Post and type into the rails console >Post.last.comments.nil? => false. So there is automatically a "ghost" comment or is that normal? That's strange to me. When I then type >Post.last.comments.last.nil? => true. So my "ghost" comment has no values in it :)? For example I cannot type <Post.last.comments.last.content. This gives me an error message.

Comment: share the code for your new form

Comment: Just try `Post.last.comments` to see what's inside, it will give you better insights, and you can use `blank?` instead of `nil?`, as comments would return `[]` and an empty array would not be considered `nil`.

Comment: `Post.last.comments` is giving me 'SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 46]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>'

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli I've edited the post with the posts#new form :)

Comment: @born4new: And `Post.last.comments.last.blank?` results to true.

Comment: If `Post.last.comments.blank?` is true, it means your post does not have any comments, which is not actually a problem. It just means you need to add comments to this post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's still strange to me, that a "delete"-link appears although this post doesn't have any comments, mhh.

Comment: 1st problem: Instead of `render root_path` I have tried `render "posts/show"`. At least now my flash message is showing up, but strangly another empty comment was saved, mhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see here is that the comment has not been saved in the database, that's the reason why it does not have an id, and that's why you get this html:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/51/comments">delete</a>
```

The id is missing.

If I were you, I would just check if the comment is present when rendering the view, so that you will only show existing comments to the user:

```
<% if comment.persisted? %>
  [...]
```

Comment: Does that mean that there is always one "not saved" comment whenever I create a new post? I've tried your solution but the sneaky "no-id-comment" is still showing up, argh!

Comment: Will correct my answer again (tired today?), I meant `comment.persisted?`

Comment: Yay, thanks a lot, the delete-link is gone :) (and sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude if that was your impression. That wasn't my intention).

Comment: Don't you worry about it :).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@post` as the main object in your controller for creating a comment, I would actually do it like so:

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.post = @post

if @comment.save
  [...]
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried it that way, but it gave me an _undefined method build_ error. With `@comment = Comment.create(comment_params)` it is working similar to my code, though my two problems are still there :(

Comment: Sorry, meant to write `new` instead of `build`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your solution with Muhammads solution and changed `render root_path` to `render "posts/show"` and now at least my custom flash message "something went wrong" shows up. Do you by chance know a way so that rails validation errors show up (for example: "Content can't be blank")? The second problem, that there is still a ghost "delete comment"-link whenever I create a post, is still there

Comment: Yes, you need to add some code to display the content of the `flash` hash to your views (check out this rails guide section about this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views). About your second problem, what is the return value of the `link_to` helper? What html does it generate?

Comment: This is the html which is generated when I create a new post (not a comment): `<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/51/comments">delete</a>`. In addition to that there are two empty `<p>` tags which usually belongs to the "name"- and "content"-field of this "ghost"-comment.

Comment: Okay, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not passing `post_id` to create method and thats why its not saving comment against the post.

Add post_id to your `post#new` form as hidden field like :

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= @post.errors.count %> Fehler:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="image-box">
    <p><%= f.file_field :image%></p>
  </div>
    <div class="title-box">
      <p><%= f.label :title, "Titel" %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :title, class: "title-field"%></p>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id %>
    </div>
     <div class="content-box">
      <p><%= f.label :content, "Inhalt" %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_area :content, class: "content-field"%></p>
    </div>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

This will resolve your issue hopefully.

Or you can allow post_id in `CommentsController` strong params and send `post_id` along with comment new form to create method & create will be like :

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment saved!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong!"
      render root_path             
    end
end

def comment_params 
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :content, :post_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your solution, changed `render root_path` to `render "posts/show"` and now at least my custom flash message "something went wrong" is showing up. Do you by chance know a way so that rails validation errors show up (for example: "Content can't be blank")? The second problem, that there is still a "delete comment"-link whenever I create a post, is still there.